# playerItemDidReachEnd reliability issues

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter, avplayeritem

I playback a video asset via `avplayer` and want to perform an action when the item has finished playing. For some reason, `playerItemDidReachEnd` doesn't get called and I'm completely lost as to why. I've also tried `addPeriodicTimeObserver` to the player and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Below is my code. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
    func setupVideo(with asset: AVAsset) {
    
    let video = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    video.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [.new, .initial], context: nil)
    
    avPlayerPlayback.replaceCurrentItem(with: video)

    avPlayerPlayback.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    let playbackLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayerPlayback)
    playbackLayer.frame = capturedVideoPlaybackView.frame
    playbackLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    capturedVideoPlaybackView.layer.addSublayer(playbackLayer)
    
    print("Player status: \(avPlayerPlayback.status.rawValue)")
    print("Player item duration: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(avPlayerPlayback.currentItem?.duration ?? CMTime.zero))")
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
   
    if keyPath == "status" {
        if let item = object as? AVPlayerItem {
            if item.status == .readyToPlay {
                // The AVPlayerItem is ready to play
                print("Item is ready to play")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                                           name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                           object: self.avPlayerPlayback.currentItem)
                    
                    self.toggleMedia(shouldHideVideo: false)
                    self.playVideo()
                    
                    print("Player status: \(avPlayerPlayback.status.rawValue)")
                    print("Player item duration: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(avPlayerPlayback.currentItem?.duration ?? CMTime.zero))")
                    print("playing video")
                }
                // Perform any additional setup or start playback
            } else if item.status == .failed {
                // Handle failure
                print("Player item failed: \(String(describing: item.error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
    }
}

func playVideo() {
   
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
//            self.avPlayerPlaybackTimeObserver =
//
//            self.avPlayerPlayback.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2) , queue: .main, using: { time in
//
//                if let currentItem = self.avPlayerPlayback.currentItem {
//
//                    let totalDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration)
//                    let secondsElapsed = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
//
//                    print(totalDuration)
//                    print(secondsElapsed)
//
//                    let progress = CGFloat(secondsElapsed / totalDuration)
//
//                    if progress >= 1 {
//                        self.handlePlaybackItemCompletion()
//                    }
//                }
//            })
                                            
        self.avPlayerPlayback.play()
    }
}

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
    // This function is called when the AVPlayer finishes playing the item
    print("Playback finished")
    handlePlaybackItemCompletion() // Call your completion handling method
}
```

Comment: I assume `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` is getting executed?

Comment: @ImShrey you mean in terms of initializing? if so yes. selector doesn't get triggered though.